# Grails Service not autowired in integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have a Sample Grails Service and trying to auto wire it inside integration test of Grails. All though the IntelliJ editor shows its auto-wired, but at runtime I always get it as null.

Integration Test is as below where I sampleService as always null.

```
class Sample {

    def sampleService;

    @Test
    public void testSample() {
        println(" Hello...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you extending `Specification` (Grails 3) or `IntegrationSpec` (Grails 2)?

Comment: I am extending none and using Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

After adding `@Autowired` explicitly to my service resolved the issue. Refer the code below

```
class Sample {

    @Autowired
    def sampleService;

    @Test
    public void testSample(){
        println(" Hello...")
    }
}
```